# Unable to explode the nested list within a json using pd.json_normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas, pyspark, json-normalize

I tried different ways to get this done, but unable to do so. Please help here.
I am trying to explode a nested json list using python pd.json_normalize. After exploding the output is coming in two rows causing duplicate PKeys. My data is below and i am trying to get a single record with "id" as pkey and values in the nested list

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "123456",
        "created_by": "abc@gmail.com",
        "created_at": "2023-12-11",
        "modified_by": "abc@gmail.com",
        "modified_at": "2023-12-11",
        "rg": {
            "id": "xyz234",
            "parent_id": "cpqrst",
            "account_id": "ntb1we"
        },
        "values": [
            {
                "value1": 100,
                "value2": 101,
                "value10": {
                    "valueid": "btqns"
                }
            },
            {
                "value1": 200,
                "value2": 201,
                "value10": {
                    "valueid": "apqns"
                }
            }
        ],
        "page_info": {
            "page": 1,
            "per_page": 100,
            "total_pages": 286,
            "total_count": 28580
        }
    }
]
```

}

my code as below to normalize and explode

```
response = requests.get(getURL, params={"page": page}, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        json_data = response.json()
        target_schema  = StructType([StructField(.................. StructField('version', LongType(), True)])

        normalized_data = pd.json_normalize(json_data,["data"],"page_info"]).explode("values").reset_index(drop=True)
        
        JSONdf = json.dumps(json.loads(normalized_data.to_json(orient="records")))
        results.append(JSONdf)

###########################modified code that worked################################
       data_df = json_normalize(json_data['data'],sep='_')
        data_df.columns = [f"{col}_data" for col in data_df.columns]

        df = 
        json_normalize(json_data['data'],'values',sep='_')
        df.columns = [f"{col}_tran" for col in df.columns]
        
        result_df = pd.concat([data_df,df],axis=1)
         ###############################################
```

This provides data in the format as below with id value 123456 repeating twice for values

Current output with id 123456 repeating in 2 rows for values.value1 and values.value2

[image: current_output]

desired output is to have a single row with id 123456 for values column having the entire list

[image: desired_output]

Any help greatly appreciated in getting the desired output. I tried all possible ways but could not get the desired output.

Comment: Can you create valid json?

Comment: Apologize there is an error in the Json, i modified it. The rg ends and values start as a separete list. So values is the list inside the data with a unique id - 123456

Comment: Unfortunately json is still invalid

Comment: Here you go, validated the json.. Its correct now

Comment: Super, tested my solution and working well

Comment: in answer bellow

Comment: @jezrael - solution does not work, its giving NULL value in all columns

Comment: I don't think exploding values will still work for me to get a unique record. What code change i need to do to have the values list displayed as is in the column without exploding?

Comment: I test json data in your question, for me working well. If all NULL values there is some naother problem. So change data for see how created null data with my solution

Comment: @jezral - i figured out and modified the code. In case some one wants to know what i have done, the modified code is updated in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adjusting  the column names inside the pd.json_normalize function according to the actual structure of your JSON data.

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample corrected JSON data
json_data = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "123456",
            "created_by": "abc@gmail.com",
            "created_at": "2023-12-11",
            "modified_by": "abc@gmail.com",
            "modified_at": "2023-12-11",
            "rg": {
                "id": "xyz234",
                "parent_id": "cpqrst",
                "account_id": "ntb1we",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value1": 100,
                        "value2": 101,
                        "value10": {
                            "valueid": "btqns"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "value1": 200,
                        "value2": 201,
                        "value10": {
                            "valueid": "apqns"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "page_info": {
                "page": 1,
                "per_page": 100,
                "total_pages": 286,
                "total_count": 28580
            }
        }
    ]
}

# Flatten the JSON and explode the "values" column
df = pd.json_normalize(json_data['data'], 'rg.values', ['id', 'created_by', 'created_at', 'modified_by', 'modified_at', 'rg.id', 'rg.parent_id', 'rg.account_id'])

print(df)
```

Comment: Values are not inside the rg. rg ends and then values start as a separate list.  Values is the list inside the data with a unique id - 123456

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
out = pd.json_normalize(json_data["data"])

print(out)
       id     created_by  created_at    modified_by modified_at   rg.id  \
0  123456  abc@gmail.com  2023-12-11  abc@gmail.com  2023-12-11  xyz234   

  rg.parent_id rg.account_id  \
0       cpqrst        ntb1we   

                                           rg.values  page_info.page  \
0  [{'value1': 100, 'value2': 101, 'value10': {'v...               1   

   page_info.per_page  page_info.total_pages  page_info.total_count  
0                 100                    286                  28580
```

If need separator `_`:

```
out = pd.json_normalize(json_data["data"], sep='_')

print(out)
       id     created_by  created_at    modified_by modified_at   rg_id  \
0  123456  abc@gmail.com  2023-12-11  abc@gmail.com  2023-12-11  xyz234   

  rg_parent_id rg_account_id  \
0       cpqrst        ntb1we   

                                           rg_values  page_info_page  \
0  [{'value1': 100, 'value2': 101, 'value10': {'v...               1   

   page_info_per_page  page_info_total_pages  page_info_total_count  
0                 100                    286                  28580
```